# Problem with airmon-ng not recognizing the windows card

Tags: networking, command-line, wireless, bash, kubuntu

I'm exploring some tools and in this case it's aircrack -ng
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVWtb.jpg)

**Network card**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yesm2.jpg)

**well my problem**

I have Ubuntu terminal on windows and when I type airmon-ng
I don't see the interfaces
ie all applications do not recognize my internet card?

How can I solve this problem

***codes I used**

Debian/Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf automake libtool pkg-config libnl-3-dev libn
apt-get install build-essential autoconf automake libtool pkg-config libnl-3-dev libnl-genl-3-dev libssl-dev ethtool shtool rfkill zlib1g-dev libpcap-dev libsqlite3-dev libpcre3-dev libhwloc-dev libcmocka-dev hostapd wpasupplicant tcpdump screen iw usbutils

apt install aircrack -ng
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FO6Gp.jpg)

Comment: You're using WSL? Ubuntu doesn't have direct access to hardware on WSL. Windows controls your hardware which is virtualized on Ubuntu.  You'll need to install Ubuntu to "bare metal" to be able to directly control hardware with Ubuntu.

Comment: @Nmath what is WLS and bare metal? so from what you're telling me it would be better to install on a partition sorry for my lack of knowledge :D

Comment: @Nmath OK. I just edited the post and yes I think it is wLS . Are following your first comment me using wls in windwos i will not be able to use this type of PROGRAM?

Comment: @Nmath so, but is it possible to do this kind of scan with the window .Or what should I do in your opinion?

Comment: @Nmath ok so it is not possible to use VM for this type of scan. But would it be possible to buy a wireless adapter for the VM? . And in windows, can I perform this scan, that is, can I put windows in monitor mode?

Comment: No, I apologize, so I have no more doubts, ending my question. Thank you for your attention and understanding :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `airmon-ng` is not possible on Windows Subsystem for Linux.

You can install Ubuntu to a VirtualBox and use a USB adapter, or install Ubuntu as a dual boot.